# Oracle 11g expdp or impdp DDL without compression

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to export some schemas DDL (no need for data) using expdp on Oracle 11.2.0.3.0. I need to try and find a way of either exporting these without compression enabled or importing ignoring the compression.

I understand you can remove compression on the import using the TRANSFORM param on 12 but I can't find anything similiar for 11.

**export:**

```
expdp /@schema_name DIRECTORY=DMP_FILES DUMPFILE=schema_name.dmp  CONTENT=METADATA_ONLY exclude=STATISTICS log=schema_name.log;
```

**import:**

```
impdp /@schema_name DIRECTORY=DMP_FILES DUMPFILE=schema_name.dmp log=schema_name.log;
```

Comment: Have you tried `COMPRESSION=NONE`?

Comment: It looks as though COMPRESSION just handles the file compression not the DDL compression?

Comment: If you want a plain text file with the DDL statements try parameter `SQLFILE`

Comment: Presumably you're talking about the `create table` compression clause? `The `segment_attributes` transform removes that but takes out other information too; there doesn't seem to be a more fine-grained approach in 11g, so that might not be an option. The only thing you can really do is use `sqlfile` and manually remove the clause.

Comment: Yes Alex the create table clause. I wrote a quick shell script in the end to loop through all the dmp files to create the sqlfile files which then were passed into sqlplus. Looks like the only way in 11g. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the only way in 11g was to use the `sqlfile` param as part of impdp to turn the existing dmp files into DDL files. I then ran these through SQLplus on the server.